# Unload JAR file from JNI

Tags: java, delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-xe2

I have a problem with the Java Native Interface.

I use the JNI in my application, everything is working fine except the fact that I'm unable to unload / release the lock from the .JAR file im accessing with the JNI.

Here is the destructor I'm using:

```
destructor Schnittstelle.Destroy;
begin
try
if (assigned(FJNIEnv)) then
begin
  ShowMessage('Destruktor');

  FJNIEnv.Free;
  FJNIEnv := nil;

  FJavaVM.JavaVM^.DetachCurrentThread(FJavaVM.JavaVM);
  FJavaVM.JavaVM^.DestroyJavaVM(FJavaVM.JavaVM);

  FJavaVM.Free;
  FJavaVM := nil;

  inherited Destroy;
end;
except
  ShowMessage('Java VM kann nicht freigegeben werden.');
  Exit;
end;
end;
```

After the desctructor is called, I try to change the JARs file name to test if the JNI stopped accessing the file, but thats not the case.

If I terminate my delphi application the JAR file is usable.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to determine if the behavior is around your code or the VM shutdown.  Run this with a very simple, non-threaded Java implementation and see if you get the same results.  If not, it may be your Java code that is preventing the VM from completely shutting down when you expect it to.

Comment: I think its the delphi code, if I terminate my delphi application the JAR file is usable.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Delphi. When you load a Java class, there is a `ClassLoader` that has the JAR file open in memory.  When you unload JNI, the JAR will stay in memory if its `ClassLoader` was not closed first. When your process terminates, only then is the JAR released. That is just how Java works. In Java 1.7+, the `URLClassLoader` class has a [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#close()) method for releasing JAR files. So you probably have a lingering `ClassLoader` still in memory at the time you unload the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have an idea how to close the ClassLoader from delphi?
I don't think that I can close the ClassLoader from the JAR file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You not specify in your question how you load the classes in the JAR file, directly via JNI o indirectly thru some Java call.

Anyway I make the assumption that class loading inside the JVM, either with [`Class.forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) or [`ClassLoader.loadClass(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) uses the same mechanisms as the JNI [`FindClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#class_operations):

> ### FindClass
>
> In JDK release 1.1, this function loads a locally-defined class. It searches the directories and zip files specified by the CLASSPATH environment variable for the class with the specified name.
>
> Since Java 2 SDK release 1.2, the Java security model allows non-system classes to load and call native methods. FindClass locates the class loader associated with the current native method; that is, the class loader of the class that declared the native method. If the native method belongs to a system class, no class loader will be involved. Otherwise, the proper class loader will be invoked to load and link the named class.
>
> Since Java 2 SDK release 1.2, **when FindClass is called through the Invocation Interface**, there is no current native method or its associated class loader. In that case, the result of **[ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()) is used. This is the class loader the virtual machine creates for applications**, and is able to locate classes listed in the java.class.path property.

Also see this other considerations over [unloading of the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764900/859646):

> **It seems that the JVM is not completely unloaded until the program exits.**

I guess that the system classloader that is referencing the jar file and the classes in it is not closed until the JVM is unloaded, ***so I guess that it is not possible to unload the jar until the program exits.***